# Evaluate:$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}|x|^{[\cos x]}$

Tags: limits

Any hint? To find the limiting value
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}|x|^{[\cos x]}$$ where ,  $[.]$ denotes the greatest integer function. The answer given is $1$.

Comment: Did you mean $\lim_{x \to 0}$? Because, as it is written, that makes no sense.

Comment: i m sry. it is so.

Comment: Hint : $\cos  x \neq 1$  until $x=0$ explicitly , limit doesn't matter. It may only  approach enough but never equal 1. Definition of limit .@Pratyush

Comment: @Pratyush , could you please join this page, you are from india right?  

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23654/room-for-pratayush-and-mann

Comment: yes....right. i m from India

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $[\cos x]=0$  here why?

$-1 \leq \cos x \leq 1$ , However, in the given condition , $x\neq 0$ however x approaches it. 
Hence the result.

Now what is $\lim_{x \to 0} x^0 = \lim_{x \to 0} 1$

I have not taken the negative limit here, but it's pretty much the same.

Comment: Just write one line before the last one $\;\lim \pm x^0=\lim 1\;$ and that's all. +1

Answer (score 3):

Let $\epsilon>0$. For every $0<|x|<\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have:

$$||x|^{[\cos x]}-1| =||x|^0-1|=|1-1|=0<\epsilon$$

Thus $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}|x|^{[\cos x]}=1$ by definition.

Notes:

- $[\cos x]=0$ when $0<|x|<\frac{\pi}{2}$
- $|x|^0=1$ since $x\not=0$

Comment: The first inequality (what you call the triangle's inequality) is *wrong*. If you want to apply the TI, it **must be** $\;||x|^{[\cos x]}-1|\le||x|^{[\cos x]}|\color{red}+1\;$ ...

Comment: You're right! I'll fix it right away. Thank you.

Comment: Any time. By the way, perhaps using your question it is easier to see the limit is $\;1\;$ **no matter** what value $\;x_0\;,\;\;0\le x_0<\dfrac\pi2\;$  ,is $\;x\;$ approaching...